# PTIJ: How did the Guide to the Perplexed affect thermodynamics?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Maimonides insists in Guide to the Perplexed that demons do not exist, despite mention of them in the Talmud. Some have later suggested that he wrote them out of existence!

So what did that do to Maxwell's Demon, and ergo, all of thermodynamics?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Aderaba, Mawell's demon was merely a THOUGHT experiment to explain how you could not DECREASE entropy in a system automatically. That Rambam says the demon does not exist is, in fact, upholding the laws of thermodynamics, namely that entropy always increases within a system. The only time we see order arise from entropy is when the process of doing so comes from Hashem (creation ex nihilo)!