# How should a Jew deal with a haunting?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, death, sheidim-demons

I know that the historical view on ghosts in Judaism is mixed. That being said, there does exists a belief in certain types of Ashkenazi folklore regarding a dybbuk. ***The belief is these being spirits of a disturbed former living soul which cling to an individual.***

While this doesn't really exist as a regular thing on modern Jewish practice/belief, the question of it still makes me curious.

In the event as Jew believes they are dealing with a haunting of some sort, what would be the course of action they should take?

Comment: Talk to their Rabbi. (Like almost everything else.)

Comment: In my view, the extenuating circumstances will allow one to rely on the opinion of the Rambam that demons do not exist :P https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23525/14008

Comment: Talk to a psychotherapist.