# Going to a mekubal to check out a shidduch

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, shidduchim-dating, practical-kabbalah

Some people go to Hassidic Rebbes or Mekubalim to give them the names of both sides of a potential shidduch to see if the names match. Are these Rabbis actually able look at the names and "see" if it will be a good shidduch? How do they do this?

To clarify, I am not looking for anecdotal evidence.

Comment: The Steipler was vehemently against this practice and it goes against the Torah(Tamim Tiyeh) ,many other great gedolim were against this practice ,read Rav Yaakov Hillel's sefer called Tamim Tiyeh or Faith and folly,amazing insights into the world of  fraud and deception .

Comment: `Not anecdotal evidence. Nothing cherry-picked. No selection bias. Anything else is OK though.` What is left? I ask again: what sort of evidence are you looking for?

Comment: @mevaqesh. Sources that discuss this issue. From both sides is fine. Nothing anecdotal or cherry-picked, though. Sam'Schoss comment is a decent start.

Comment: The main discussions that I have seen on this matter are based on [May a Man and Woman Marry if Their Fathers or Mothers Have the Same Name ?](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=348) Aside from that, most discussions involve the statement that it is rare to find actual mekubalim that are worth going to. Many times the people that are called *mekubalim* are not proper.

Comment: @sam see this on rabbi hillel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45058/1857

Comment: @sam Concerning Faith and Folly, read carefully and completely the approbation from Rav Kaduri z"l found at the beginning.

Comment: If the answer was yes, how would you investigate this? If the answer was no, how would you distinguish it from any other mystic that people go to for advice?

Answer (score 1):

I've met some people in Jerusalem who can do this. My first encounter was in the Bucharim section with a certain "chacham Betzalel" many years ago. There was a line of people waiting there. When my turn came, he asked me my father's name which he wrote down, then asked me my name and he wrote it down. Then he wrote down my mother's name without asking me. He then proceeded to tell me all sorts of things about both without my saying a word. He also said they were not compatible (turns out they divorced). All of what he said was spot on. However, I then went to Rabbi Yaakov Hillel and he told me, yes i know him but don't trust him. I found out later from other sources that this man uses forces of tum'a to do what he does. So from my experience the phenomena is real (and Rabbi Hillel [agrees](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45058/1857)) but one must be very careful to ask one of the Gedolei Hador (greatest torah scholars of the generation) to be sure it is not from the bad side. (I can give you a name of one who does not hide what he sees if you like)

As to where these powers come from (from the good side), see for example Chovot Halevavot gate 8 ch.4

> And when you do this with a faithful heart and a pure soul, your mind
>   will become illuminated, and you will see the path to all of the
>   exalted qualities, and the yetzer (evil inclination) will not have a
>   way to reach you and entice you, and you will reach the status of one
>   treasured by G-d. A new, strange, supernal sense will arouse in you,
>   unfamiliar to you of all the senses you are used to knowing, as the
>   wise man said: "A man's wisdom makes his face to shine, and the
>   boldness of his face is changed" (Koheles 8:1), then you will perceive
>   the great matters, and you will see the deep secrets, with your pure
>   soul, pure heart, and strong faith

and earlier in Gate 8 ch.3 #10

> And the Creator will open for him the gates of His knowledge, and
>   reveal to him secrets of His wisdom, and G-d will put His attention to
>   guide and lead him, and He won't abandon him to himself and his
>   (limited) ability, as the entire psalm 23 says: "The L-ord is my
>   shepherd; I shall not lack" (Tehilim 23:1), until the end. And he will
>   be on an exalted level, among the levels of the Chasidim, and a high
>   level among the Tzadikim (righteous), and he will be able to see
>   without his physical eyes, and hear without his physical ears, and
>   speak without a tongue, and he will sense things without his physical
>   senses, and be able to picture them without need for a comparison.

Comment: The OP said he was seeking "Not anecdotal evidence" so I don't think this is a good answer for him if it's an answer at all.

Comment: Can you clarify how you know that the perception that the Hovot Halevavot is referring to includes determining marital compatibility based on names? | Personally that seems very unlikely, especially considering that the Hovot Halevavot's background, his disbelief in astrology, etc.

Comment: @mevaqesh just showing that some people have a divinely inspired  sixth sense. what disbelief in astrology (source?) and what does that have to do with this?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying that you are only claiming that the Hovot Halevavot is evidence that some people can have special wisdom, and isn't meant to demonstrate the OP's question.

Comment: @mevaqesh special divinely inspired wisdom yes. as u yourself cite  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78758/going-to-a-mekubal-to-check-out-a-shidduch/78781?noredirect=1#comment237252_78758

Comment: All knowledge is special, and all of it can be credited to the divine. This is the theme of the 4th berakha in the `Amidah; "Honen Hada'at".

Comment: `So from my experience the phenomena [sic] is real` What part of your experience indicated that it wasn't hot reading, cold reading, or anything in between? | `but one must be very careful to ask one of the Gedolei Hador (greatest torah scholars of the generation) to be sure it is not from the bad side.` Was this also part of your experience or do you have a source for it?

Comment: I think that the practice of Chassidim to ask their Admor, e.g. Gur, is not comparable tot the mekubal/necromenser/fortune-teller. This is firstly in way to receive a bracha and agreement from the  Rabby they follow.