# Can another Prophet appear before Moshiach and Eliyahu?

Tags: messiah, nevua-prophecy

The Talmud [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.11a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) that Malachi is the last Prophet:

> ת״ר משמתו נביאים האחרונים חגי זכריה ומלאכי נסתלקה רוח הקודש מישראל ואף על פי כן היו משתמשין בבת קול
>
> The Sages taught: After the last of the prophets, Haggai, Zechariah, and Malachi, died, the Divine Spirit departed from the Jewish people. But nevertheless, they were utilizing a Divine Voice.

My point is that Malachi cannot be considered the "last prophet" in the **absolute sense**, since we know that Moshiach will be a prophet too and will come after Malachi.

So my question is: is it **conceivable** that G-d could send another Prophet after Malachi, **before** Eliyahu and Moshiach arrive?

Comment: This site doesn't have the precise timing, but says, " One of our traditions regarding the advent of the Messianic Era is that it will mark the return of prophecy among the Jewish people." https://www.aish.com/jl/li/m/48931432.html -- the use of the word "advent" might indicate even prior to the messiah's arrival. And of course, bava basra ""After the destruction of the Holy Temple the power of prophecy was taken from the prophets and given to the mentally ill and to children. "

Comment: I think it's a really bad idea for us to claim that we know all the answers (or maybe any of them) about what will happen during and after the coming of Meshiach. I believe the Rambam says the same in Iggeres Teiman. We'll find out when it happens. "Prediction is hard, especially about the future."

Comment: @MichoelR I think you misunderstood my question. I'm asking whether it is **conceivable**, based on primary Jewish texts, that a prophet could be sent by G-d before Eliyahu and Moshiach arrive.

Comment: So I'm answering - a lot more things are conceivable than we guess, because we are never really going to understand the primary sources until things have happened. I think the Rambam says that. In the meantime, we try out ideas, but we have to be willing to let Hashem call the shots. In the end we will know what was conceivable.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110993/170 and/or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117715/170

Comment: Why would we think that there could not be a prophet before the arrival of Eliyahu? The Gemara there doesn't seem to hint to that.

Answer (score 1):

In *Guide for the Perplexed* 2:36 Rambam writes:

> The same circumstance, prevalence of sadness and dulness, was undoubtedly the direct cause of the interruption of prophecy during the exile: for can there be any greater misfortune for man than this: to be a slave bought for money in the service of ignorant and voluptuous masters, and powerless against them as they unite in themselves the absence of true knowledge and the force of all animal desires? Such an evil state has been prophesied to us in the words, "They shall run to and fro to seek the word of God, but shall not find it" (Amos viii. 12); "Her king and her princes are among the nations, the law is no more, her prophets also find no vision from the Lord" (Lam. ii. 9). This is a real fact, and the cause is evident; the pre-requisites [of prophecy] have been lost. In the Messianic period--may it soon commence--prophecy will therefore again be in our midst, as has been promised by God.
>
> ([Friedlander translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp123.htm))

It sounds like as soon as these circumstances return to how they were, there can be new prophets.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Moses of Coucy, in his magnum opus, the SeMaG (Sefer Mitzvot Gadol) (end of introduction to the positive commandments) posits, that until Elijah the prophet appears, there will not be ANY other prophet.

> ואחר פטירת משה רבינו עמדו נביאים לישראל . . , ועל ידי כך אמרו הגוים כי
> הנביאים נתנבאו בתורה חדשה שלהם, לכך שלח להם הקב"ה ביד מלאכי, שהוא אחרון
> לכל הנביאים ואמר שני דברים בסוף דבריו לחתום כל הנבואות, "הנה אנכי שולח
> לכם את אלי' הנביא לפני בא יום הגדול והנורא", כלומר הנני אחרון לכל
> הנביאים, **וממני עד שיבוא אליהו לא יעמוד נביא**, והנני אומר לכם בשם הקב"ה
> "זכרו תורת משה עבדי אשר ציותי אותו בחורב על כל ישראל חוקים ומשפטים",
> כלומר אל יעלה על לבבכם שהנביאים שעמדו לפני נתנבאו בחילוף תורת משה, כי
> כולם לחזק תורת משה באו". עכ"ל